# Efficiently calculating grid-based point density in 3d point cloud

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, point-clouds

I have a 3d point cloud matrix, and I am trying to calculate the largest point density within a smaller volume inside the matrix. I am currently using a 3D grid-histogram system where I loop through every point in the matrix and increase the value of the corresponding grid square. Then, I can simply find the max value of the grid matrix.

I have already written code that works, but it is horribly slow for what I am trying to do

```
import numpy as np

def densityPointCloud(points, gridCount, gridSize):
    hist = np.zeros((gridCount, gridCount, gridCount), np.uint16)

    rndPoints = np.rint(points/gridSize) + int(gridCount/2)
    rndPoints = rndPoints.astype(int)


    for point in rndPoints:
        if np.amax(point) < gridCount and np.amin(point) >= 0:
            hist[point[0]][point[1]][point[2]] += 1

    return hist


cloud = (np.random.rand(100000, 3)*10)-5
histogram = densityPointCloud(cloud , 50, 0.2)
print(np.amax(histogram))
```

Are there any shortcuts I can take to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start:

```py
import numpy as np
import time
from collections import Counter

# if you need the whole histogram object
def dpc2(points, gridCount, gridSize):

    hist = np.zeros((gridCount, gridCount, gridCount), np.uint16)
    rndPoints = np.rint(points/gridSize) + int(gridCount/2)
    rndPoints = rndPoints.astype(int)
    inbounds = np.logical_and(np.amax(rndPoints,axis = 1) < gridCount, np.amin(rndPoints,axis = 1) >= 0)

    for point in rndPoints[inbounds,:]:
        hist[point[0]][point[1]][point[2]] += 1

    return hist

# just care about a max point
def dpc3(points, gridCount, gridSize):

    rndPoints = np.rint(points/gridSize) + int(gridCount/2)
    rndPoints = rndPoints.astype(int)
    inbounds = np.logical_and(np.amax(rndPoints,axis = 1) < gridCount,
        np.amin(rndPoints,axis = 1) >= 0)
    # cheap hashing
    phashes = gridCount*gridCount*rndPoints[inbounds,0] + gridCount*rndPoints[inbounds,1] + rndPoints[inbounds,2]
    max_h, max_v = Counter(phashes).most_common(1)[0]

    max_coord = [(max_h // (gridCount*gridCount)) % gridCount,(max_h // gridCount) % gridCount,max_h % gridCount]
    return (max_coord, max_v)

# TESTING
cloud = (np.random.rand(200000, 3)*10)-5
t1 = time.perf_counter()
hist1 = densityPointCloud(cloud , 50, 0.2)
t2 = time.perf_counter()
hist2 = dpc2(cloud,50,0.2)
t3 = time.perf_counter()
hist3 = dpc3(cloud,50,0.2)
t4 = time.perf_counter()
print(f"task 1: {round(1000*(t2-t1))}ms\ntask 2: {round(1000*(t3-t2))}ms\ntask 3: {round(1000*(t4-t3))}ms")
print(f"max value is {hist3[1]}, achieved at {hist3[0]}")
np.all(np.equal(hist1,hist2)) # check that results are identical
# check for equal max - histogram may be multi-modal so the point won't
# necessarily match
np.unravel_index(np.argmax(hist2, axis=None), hist2.shape)
```

The idea is to do all the if/and comparisons once: let numpy do them (effectively in C) rather then doing them 'manually' inside a Python loop. This also lets us only iterate over the points that will lead to `hist` being incremented.

You can also consider using a sparse data structure for `hist` if you think your cloud will have lots of empty space - memory allocation can become a bottleneck for very large data.

Did not scientifically benchmark this but appears to run ~2-3x faster (v2) and 6-8x faster (v3)! If you'd like *all* the points which are tied for the max. density, it would be easy to extract those from the `Counter` object.

Comment: 800ms -> 28ms. Thanks!